# Cannot authenticate using devise_cas_authenticatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm following the instruction at https://github.com/nbudin/devise_cas_authenticatable. However, using this and `before_filter :authenticate_user!` still makes the app trying to authenticate using the database authentication strategy for devise. Below is the devise config file:

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'

  config.cas_base_url = 'https://cas.uwaterloo.ca/cas'

  # If true, uses the password salt as remember token. This should be turned
  # to false if you are not using database authenticatable.
  config.use_salt_as_remember_token = true

  # ==> Configuration for :token_authenticatable
  # Defines name of the authentication token params key
  config.token_authentication_key = :auth_token

  # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you replace `:database_authenticatable` in your user model?

```
devise :cas_authenticatable, ...
```

See the readme for [`devise_cas_authenticatable`](https://github.com/nbudin/devise_cas_authenticatable) on github.